# Creation of anonymous userdata variables

Tags: lua, anonymous-objects

I'm working with the lua C api to run scripts that interface with native clases. I'm taking advantage of Qt's MOC for the run time type information. So far, I've implemented the creation, deletion, and indexing of all the classes I want lua to be able to talk to.

Here's an example script of what I can do now:

```
myObject = MyClass.new()  --creates new userdata
otherObject = OtherClass.new()  --creates new userdata

myObject:functionForOthers(otherObject)  --method that takes userdata as argument
```

In that script, `otherObject` gets created and stays on the stack. It is then passed through `functionForOthers()` which accepts `OtherClass` objects as the argument.

But what if I didn't want `otherObject` to be put on the stack? What if I wanted it to be an anonymous variable where is exists only in the scope of the function call?

```
myObject = MyClass.new()

myObject:functionForOthers(OtherClass.new())
```

This still works, but the `OtherObject` instance gets created but *never assigned to a variable* leaving it on the stack unreachable until the scope ends. This doesn't cause any direct problems, but it bothers the memory-efficient part of me.

I have a lot of native code handling the backend of these operations, but the basic gist of it is that `new` is a field of global tables `MyClass` and `OtherClass` that points to a native CreateObject function. From there, an instance of the class is created and stored in a userdata after calling `lua_newuserdata()`

The `functionForOthers()` call makes use of the `__index` metamethod that points to a native IndexObject function which calls the method if it exists.

What is the basic approach to implementing anonymous userdata variables? I still want both scripts to be valid approaches, I just want a way to keep the second script's `OtherClass` object in scope until the function call is done.

Comment: Why having additional local variable is a problem?  Creating local variable is very cheap in Lua VM.

Comment: There isn't a problem with using local variables. The problem is that the second script works as well, but leaves unreferenced objects on the stack forever. I would prefer to use the second scripts structure because this type of call will be made a LOT in my scripts.

Comment: In a Lua program containing `func(create_new_object())` a new object exists only while function `func` is executed.  This new object is removed from the stack immediately when `func` returns (if I understand it correctly).

Comment: I would have thought so as well, but when I print something out in the objects destructor, that new object created in the function call was still hanging around after the function call was long over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels like you're misunderstanding some parts of Lua.

Having some object passed as an argument to a function doesn't "leave" that object on stack. The stack only store a reference to the object. The other reference to the very same object is stored in `otherObject` variable. When you pass a variable as argument to `functionForOthers()` you get that reference copied by value to the stack, and that reference gets popped off the stack as soon as called function returns control.

The object itself is stored on Lua heap. It will get destroyed/collected eventually, when garbage collector will find that there's no references left to that object. The object is not destroyed at the end of the scope, only reference is lost. And it's up to garbage collector when to actually delete the object.

If you worry about the memory, you can call `collectgarbage()` periodically. That might stutter your program for some time though, so choose the right moment. Otherwise you can ignore it completely, just be sure you're not collecting references to objects in some long-living structure (global variables, registry, or your own dictionaries/caches). The references on stack are dropped quickly, unless you unwittingly create very deep or infinite recursive call. The object that can't be reached will be deleted automatically, that's the way mark-and-sweep garbage collector work.

Comment: So you're saying that given enough time, that object would go away on it's own since it wasn't referenced? Kinda bothers me, but I guess that makes life easier hahaha. Thans for the info!